# Trotter splitting and entanglement entropy

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, computational-physics

I have heard that a numerical solution to the Schrodinger equation using the Trotter splitting formula for a many-body Hamiltonian can cause an artificial increase in the entanglement entropy. I was not able to get a reference from the guy at the bar I was talking to before we left. Could anybody explain why this is the case?